# Is there a way assign value to variable on workbook_open event, and have that value carry to other modules?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Variables tab in a workbook that allows me to just change the cell values and have them picked up in the VBA code variable.

[Worksheet Variable page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoKWQ.png)

The variables are declared as Global in a subprocedure:
[Global Variables Declared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1hAk.png)

Values are defined in the workbook_open event:
[Workbook Open Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKAAL.png)

However, when I add a *watch* for that variable in a different module, it is saying **out of context**.
[Module trying to pick up variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sfkD.png)

I tried creating a Global Variable as constant and realized you cant set those to a cell reference (or I couldn't figure that part out).

Then tried the problem above to no avail. Cannot seem to find a solution online...

Comment: Yes, but declare it as `Public`, on top of a **standard module**. Where are the declarations you show? If they are declared on top of `ThisWorkbook` module, you should invoke them using the code module name: `ThisWorkbook.ServerName`, or if in a sheet code module, using the respective sheet Code module name. Something as `Sheet2.ServerName`, but `Sheet2` is **not the sheet name**! It is the one you can see in VBE for each sheet (before the sheet name between parenthesis). Then, what do you mean by "you cant set those to a cell reference"?

Comment: I am editing an old file that was left to me and it's quite a mess, so I've been trying to frankenstein the code to work; but it may be easier to just rewrite all of it...

Comment: It would not be wrong if you **understand** how to use such variables... Do you understand what I said in the above comment? If so, does your trial respect those requirements? If not, ask for clarifications, please...

Comment: When I go big, I create a sheet called settings, that I super hide with the command `.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden`. The data is still accessable when the sheet is hidden :)

Comment: I think I understand... I've just referenced the cell reference in the module itself opposed to trying to carry the variable from a workbook open event...